# Kingston USB files keep disappearing

Tags: laptop, usb, memory, recycle-bin

I've been reorganizing my files on my Kingston USB and the files keep disappearing before my eyes. I have checked the recycle bin and there is no sign of them there. I've checked the C: drive on my laptop; it locates them but if I try to open them it says they have been modified or removed.

Comment: You should probably consult with a data recovery company before going any further. You will need to try and recover these files. Try recuva http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/gr/recuva-review.htm

Answer (score 1):

You probably have fake capacity USB stick (yes, especially if it says "Kingston" on it, they're big target for this thriving industry of fake capacity memory storage), and from this your problems arise. Get a tool like [F3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/) or [h2testw](http://www.heise.de/download/h2testw.html) to check it. If so, most of your data on stick is unrecoverably lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different machine/port too and rule that out. Sounds like the stick is going bad, I'd get what you can off it right now and persevere with it.